# Is there a graphical overview of the HatchStyle enumeration?

Tags: .net, brush, drawing2d, hatchstyle

A hatch pattern is made from two colors: one defined by the BackgroundColor, which fills the background and one for the lines that form the pattern over the background defined by the ForegroundColor property. The [HatchStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle.aspx) defines what type of pattern the brush has and can be any value from the HatchStyle enumeration. There are more than fifty elements in the HatchStyle enumeration.

The following illustration shows an ellipse filled with a horizontal hatch pattern.

[image]

[Just like for the colors defined in the Color class](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/colors/ColorTable.htm), I'd like to have a graphical list of all styles defined in HatchStyle, but found none in the MSDN. Do you know of such a overview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google does find a lot of info:

http://www.drewnoakes.com/snippets/GdiColorChart/

http://www.pardesiservices.com/softomatix/reflectionhatch.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/HatchStyleComboBox.aspx

Have your pick  :)

Comment: Could you add an actual image?

Comment: @mafutrct: Not really, I would have to ask permission for that  :)

Comment: Second link is down